# Adjust div width to content CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div with list of inputs (checkboxes) and labels.

Some labels are very long words or sentences and I would like to adjust my div to the length of content.

At the moment, if the word is too long, the part of it goes to the next line (the new `li` element will be created, like in second screenshot, second label is now on the second and third lines) and I would like to find such CSS rules, which allows to change (to adapt) the size of div, so the words (labels for inputs) stays on one line.

Is it possible to achieve this with help of CSS?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a code example of this to play around?

Comment: `div` is a block element and so it will have `100%` width. But not `ul` or `li`. You can give `100%` width to `ul` and the use `text-overflow: ellipsis`, so that your `li` won't break into two lines even if it is so long.

Comment: just use `word-break:break-all;` in your css for `label`. like this: `label{ word-break:break-all; } `

Answer (score 0):

with help of css you can break word and move to next line `word-break: break-all` check below example,

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.word {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<h2>normal (default):</h2>
<div>Thisissomeveryveryverylongandwillfitinsideddiv word. Words will break according to usual rules.</div>
<h2>word-break</h2>
<div class="word">Thisissomeveryveryverylongandwillfitinsideddiv word. This text will break at any character.</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to break it, but to keep on the same line

Comment: if you don't want to break you `word warp`

Answer (score 0):

You can use hyphens property in css:

```css
/* Just a test, you can rename class */
div.container {
    width: 100px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    color: #000;
}

/* Breaking-words with line-wrapping at &shy or &hyphens */
.hyphensM {
    -moz-hyphens: manual;
 -ms-hyphens: manual;
 -webkit-hyphens: manual;
 hyphens: manual
}

/* Breaking-words, no line-wrapping. Depends on the language used <html lang="...">*/
.hyphensA {
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
 -ms-hyphens: auto;
 -webkit-hyphens: auto;
 hyphens: auto
}

/* None, no breaking-words and line-wrapping */
.hyphensN {
    -moz-hyphens: none;
 -ms-hyphens: none;
 -webkit-hyphens: none;
 hyphens: none
}
```

```html
<div class="container" lang="en">
    <p class="hyphensM">Thisisaveryveryveryveryveryvery&shylooooooooooooooooooooooongsentence.</p>
    <p class="hyphensA">Thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylooooooooooooooooooooooongsentence.</p>
    <p class="hyphensN">Thisisaveryveryveryveryveryverylooooooooooooooooooooooongsentence.</p>
</div>
```

Sources: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Answer (score -1):

you can use scrollbar feature to stay all content in one line

```
#div{
    overflow-x: scroll;
{
```

this property add x-scroll bar to your div or use     `overflow-x: hidden;` to hidden content

Comment: This is not what he asked.